# jQuery selector: match array attribute's n-th value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an attribute for a set of HTML5 objects that is an array.  Something like

```
<button attr=[1,0,0,0,1,1]>test</button>
<button attr=[1,1,0,0,1,1]>test</button>
...
```

How do I formulate a jQuery selector to match only elements whose n-th value of attr is 1?  Something like `$("attr[1]=1")` that would only select the second button from this example (this syntax does not work, but I wrote it just to give an idea of what I need).

In my case I am not dealing with buttons but with other types of objects, I just wanted so simplify the context of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom filter to select only the matched elements.

```html
<button data-attr="[1,0,0,0,1,1]">button 1</button>
<button data-attr="[1,1,0,0,1,1]">button 2</button>
```

Note that `attr` is not a valid html attribute for button. I'd suggest you use the `data-attr` instead. You can use `.data('attr')` to get the data back.

```js
var selected = $('button').filter(function (idx) {
    var attr = $(this).data('attr');
    return attr && attr[1] == 1;
});
alert(selected.html());
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8Sd7/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own selector like this (i called it "array", you can use a better name here):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].array = function (elem, index, match) {
    var params = match[3].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s*,\s*/),
        attribute = params[0],
        arrayindex = parseInt(params[1]),
        matchvalue = params[2],
        value = JSON.parse($(elem)[attribute](attribute));
    return value[arrayindex] == matchvalue;
};
```

Then, use it like any other selector where the first parameter is the name of the attribute, the second parameter is the index in your array and the third parameter is the expected value:

```
$('button:array(attr,1,1)');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/uDnK8/2/